# Зачем нужна перегрузка операторов

Tags: c++

Зачем нужна перегрузка операторов?
Можете написать код для большей усваимости

Comment: Самая вредная примочка ООП. Чтобы непосвященные совсем запутались.

Comment: avp, на java программируете? иногда писать MyFirstObject+=MySecondObject; удобнее, чем MyFirstObject=MyFirstObject.Add(MySecondObject); хоть реализуется оно практически одинково, даже возможно одно через другое

Comment: (Оффтопя) К слову, ad-hoc полимфоризм (который, в частности, используется при перегрузке операторов) не является «примочкой» ООП и прекрасно существует безотносительно этой парадигмы. ООП — это, в основном, к полимфоризму через подтипы (который, обычно, и называют просто «полиморфизмом»).

Comment: Сейчас еще остались не ООП языки в которых можно перегружать операции ??? Не помню, в АДЕ это есть ?

Кстати, вообще-то я имел в виду **перегружаемые пользователем** операции, что к java не относится.

Comment: 1. АДА -- первый международно стандартизованный язык ООП. 2. Смотрите перегрузку в haskell.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Чтобы Вы могли совершать с классами те же операции, что и со стандартными типами данных. Например:

```
class CMoneys
{
  int iDol;
  int iCen;
public:
  CMoneys(int Dollars, int Cents)
  {
    iDol=Dollars;
    iCen=Cents;
  }
  CMoneys(const CMoneys& Money);
//////Some code//////
  CMoneys operator +(CMoneys mon)
  {
    return (iDol + Money.iDol, iCen + Money.iCen);
  }
}
```

////////////// В Функции main /////////////

```
CMoneys M1(1, 2), M2(2, 3), M;
M = M1 + M2;   /////////////// Понимаем, как М (M1.iDol + M2.iDol, M1.iCen + M2.iCen)
```

То есть благодаря перегрузке операторов мы можем выполнять со своими классами те же операции, что и со встроенными типами данных. О перегрузке хорошо написано [Здесь](http://khpi-iip.mipk.kharkiv.edu/library/pgm/shildt/glava6.pdf)

Comment: Stop Cclass madness!

Comment: Why "madness"? You not like this programming style? I always write 'C' before class name, such as letter 'i' before int variable or 'ch' before char variable...

Comment: http://www.jelovic.com/articles/stupid_naming.htm

Comment: Не убедительно. Если Вы хороший программист, то Вы должны знать, когда класс, имя которого начинается на 'C' будет конфликтовать с разработанным Вами. Тем более, что в библиотеках языка С++ я ни разу не встречал классы, конфликтующие с моими собственными. И никто ещё из моего окружения их не встречал. Так что это дело сугуб личное. Вот если компилятор будет ругаться -- тогда да, тогда префикс надо будет сменить...

Comment: Классы в С??? Кажется, я что-то пропустил, когда учил этот язык

Comment: Исправил, прошу прощения. Имеются в виду те библиотеки и файлы заголовков, которые используются не только для С++, но и для С. Хотя там четкой границы нет. Тем более что никто не будет называть свой класс CView или CDialog. Короче, за 4 года программирования у меня ни разу не было конфликтов имен классов, значит, это замечание не всегда справедливо, и точка.

Comment: Учитывая, что теперь уже в с++ есть такая полезная штука как namespace - возможно и неактуально, но каких-либо серьезных причин называть свои классы с определенной буквы не вижу все равно. Венгерская нотация тоже противоречивая штука.

Comment: Cмысл не в самой букве, а в том, что она увеличивает вероятность конфликта имен. Тем более, что вышеописанный код, во-первых, никогда не вызовет конфликта, а во-вторых, это лишь пример. Не нравится буква С -- пишите Т;). Это лишь для того, чтоб любой программист, разбирающий мой код, мог точно сказать: "Это класс [целое/строка/символ/структура], и ничего более". Опять-таки, не нравится -- пишите иначе, это сугубо личное дело каждого.

Comment: <i> Тем более, что вышеописанный код, во-первых, никогда не вызовет конфликта, а во-вторых, это лишь пример</i>
CMoney - вероятно. А CTime - очень даже вероятно вызовыет конфликт. Использование префикса T в качестве префикса для класса - та еще дурь. А статью Вы явно читали невнимательно, или не прониклись. 

P.S. а разве при сложении центов и долларов сотни центов не должны конвертироваться в соответствующее кол-во долларов?

Answer (score 4):

В некоторых случаях перегрузка все-таки удобнее своих функций с именами, особенно если подобные операторы введены вне программирования - например действия с полиномами (надеюсь, никто не будет спорить что два полинома можно сложить, вычесть и умножить и получить новый полином), сложение интенсивностей звука, действия с комплексными числами, приведенные выше действия с суммами денег или любыми другими величинами, записанными в виде X рублей Y копеек/ X футов Y дюймов и т.п.

Comment: Желательно бы увидеть пример кода для комплексных чисел...
Сталоб понятнее)

Comment: Похоже Вы говорите об удобстве программирования для специалистов (не профессиональных программистов) из некоторых прикладных областей (о проблемно-ориентированном программировании).

Вас никогда не просили помочь найти *маленькую ошибочку* в подобном творении ?

Comment: дай дураку стеклянный ...кхм, так он и ...кхм разобъёт и руки порежет. А если правильно и с умом использовать, то никаких проблем не должно возникать.

Comment: Вообще говоря, операторы бывают разными. Скажем, `+` или `==` — это, по сути своей, такие же функции, просто с инфиксной нотацией и «странным» именем. Нет *никакой* разницы между `plus(a, b)` и `a + b`. А вот про `=` уже можно задуматься.

Comment: Но я считаю, что настоящие ф-ции должны предшествовать операторам. Т.е. если необходисо сложение,  то реализуйте ф-цию add(), а затем уже начинайте думать о перегрузке операторов. При этом перегруженный оператор + легко реализовать через уже написанную и, надеюсь, отлаженную ф-цию add().

Comment: @avp Так я и написал в некоторых случаях, перегрузкой не стоит сильно увлекаться и пихать её всюду, что, впрочем, верно и для любого действия. В подобных творениях не просили, но написать все через пень-колоду чтобы потом не найти маленькую ошибку можно и в самой простой процедурной программе без всякого ООП.

Comment: Ну так, именно. `#define true false`, и приятного дебага ;)

Comment: тогда уже #define true (Math.random()>0.5)

Comment: @Alerr например, вот: http://dmtsoft.ru/bn/370/as/oneaticleshablon/

Answer (score 3):

Зачем нужна? А затем, что удобно. На самом деле, честно говоря, перегрузка операторов только запутывает.

Понятно откуда она растет - из обобщения принципа перегрузки функций, ведь перегруженные операторы - суть те же пользовательские функции. Ну, и программисты жуткие лентяи и не любят писать стопицот букв в коде программы.

Касательно того когда перегружать и зачем. Это гораздо более интересный вопрос. Могу сказать следующее: выгодно перегружать операторы = (практически обязательно, если пользовательский класс содержит указатели куда-либо и нужно корректно отрабатывать ситуацию создания копии существующего или временнего объекта класса), оператор -> (если реализуете класс с семантикой классического указателя), оператор [] (если реализуете класс массива или коллекции и есть необходимость доступа к элементу этой коллекции поиндексу), оператор () ( если реализуете концепцию функтора). К остальным перегрузкам следует относиться с осторожностью. Во-первых, сутьопераций должна быть ясна. Например, оператор + должен складывать объекты, а не вычитать или, скажем, считать налоги. Т.е. его стоит реализовывать для пользовательских строковых типов или численных типов. А вот для объектов бизнес-логики или моделирующих физические процессы использование этого оператора нерационально - становится неясно, что хотел сказать автор кода. Поэтому вызовы функций с говорящими именами - наш метод, правильный и надежный. Во-вторых, нет возможности переопределить приоритеты операторов. В третьих, не стоит плодить кучу перегрузок одного и того же оператора для случая разных комбинаций типов. Это вкупе с операторами приведения типов очень быстро приводит к бардаку. И может в некоторых случаях удивить компилятор, ну, и программиста тоже.

Comment: Отличный ответ. Выводы для практики:

1) Не перегружайте операторы.

2) Избегайте чужого кода с перегруженными операторами (лучше перепишите его).

3) Не считайте, что функции с говорящими именами позволяют делать действительно понятные программы. Это иллюзия комментариев. Хороший комментарий говорит не о том, **что делаем** (это и так ясно из кода), а о том **зачем именно это делаем**.

Иначе будут у вас плохо отлавливаемые при многолетнем сопровождении программ ошибочки.

Comment: перегрузку можно употреблять с математическими операторами или хотя бы широко известными типами такими как списки, карты, графы и.т.п а в остальном да хорошо делает код нечитабельным