# Переопределение операторов для объединения массивов (C++)

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Пытаюсь переопределить операторы `+` и `+=` для сложения массивов.
Получаю ошибку:

> Выражение должно относиться к целочисленному типу или типу перечисления без области видимости

Что я делаю не так?

```
Task* operator+(Task* &newTasks)
{
    int num1 = sizeof(tasks) / sizeof(Task);
    int num2 = sizeof(newTasks) / sizeof(Task);
    Task *finalTask = new Task[num1 + num2];
    for (int i = 0; i < num1; i++)
    {
        finalTask[i] = tasks[i];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < num2; i++)
    {
        finalTask[i+num1] = newTasks[i];
    }

    return finalTask;
}
Task* operator+=(Task *&newTasks)
{
    Task *finalTask = tasks + newTasks; // Тут ошибка

}
```

Comment: А ваши перегруженные операторы объявленны в классе? или вне его?

Comment: Хотя в любом случае вам нужно оперировать не с указателями на объект, а с объектами. Для этого нужно сделать класс а-ля "контейнер", либо использовать уже существующие контейнеры (std::vector, например)

Comment: Ради интереса, вы перед Си на чем писали?

Comment: Перед C ни на чем не писал. Только Паскаль в школе. 
Не совсем понял формулировку "сделать класс а-ля 'контейнер'"

Comment: @Bloodskys во-первых это не `С` а `С++` - потому как чистый `С` не допускает перегрузку операторов, и там нет классов (но есть структуры). Контейнер (в общем контексте) - это объект, способный содержать в себе множество однотипных объектов (массив - вполне себе контейнер). То, что сейчас в коде у вас - и не должно работать. Могу вам посоветовать почитать про перегрузку операторов (например http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/31511/, то, что оператор объявлен в классе - да, это важно).

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы не можете перегружать операторы для непользовательских типов.

В этом предложении

```
Task *finalTask = tasks + newTasks; // Тут ошибка
```

у вас имеет место попытка сложения двух указателей.

Для указателей оператор + не определен. Поэтому компилятор выдает сообщение об ошибке.

Вам следует ваши указатели "обернуть" в какой-нибудь класс и определить функцию `operator +` для этого класса.

Также, похоже, вы вообще некорректно определяете оператор. Этот оператор должен быть либо функцией-членом класса с одним параметром, либо отдельно определенной функцией с двумя параметрами, так как вы хотите перегрузить бинарный оператор +, а не унарный оператор +.

Имейте в виду, что данное выражение

```
int num2 = sizeof(newTasks) / sizeof(Task);
```

делает совсем не то, что вы думаете. Данное выражение вообще может быть равно 0, так как `sizeof(newTasks)` - это размер указателя, который обычно равен 4 или 8 байтам в зависимости от используемой среду выполнения программы. Значение `sizeof(Task)` может быть даже больше 8 байтов, в результате чего и с учетом арифметики для целых чисел вы можете получить 0.

Поэтому вы должны хранить где-то размер массива, который был выделен динамически, и на первый элемент которого указывает указатель. Например, если вы создадите свой класс, то вы можете хранить это значение в члене данных этого класса.

Answer (score 1):

При перегрузке оператора для пользовательского класса аргументоми всё же должны выступать не указатели, а ссылки (скорее всего константные). При этом бинарные симметричные операторы (типа `+`) лучше перегружать в виде свободной функции для обеспечения возможности неявного преобразования аргументов.

[Пример](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bda95196d71defb7):

```
#include <iostream>

struct S {
    S(int i) : i(i) {}
    int i = 0;
};

S operator+ (const S& lhs, const S& rhs) { 
    return {lhs.i + rhs.i}; 
}

int main()
{
    S s1(1);
    S s2(2);

    S s3 = s1 + s2;
    std::cout << s3.i << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`operator +=`, как минимум, должен возвращать ссылку на объект. В итоге он (т.к. это все-таки присваивание) должен делать `return *this`

Кроме того, если Вы планируете сделать что-то типа:

```
Task a1[10];
Task a2[10];
Task a3[20] = a1 + a2;
```

То этого (насколько я понимаю) сделать просто-напросто невозможно. Нужно, как верно отметил Юрий Орлов в комментарии, реализовывать собственный контейнер, или использовать существующие.

Т.е., фактически, Вы пытаетесь переопределить операции `+` и `+=` для указателей (в С++ массивы и указателе являются довольно близкими родственниками, вплоть до идентичного поведения в большинстве случаев), которые являются базовым типом, и переопределение операторов для них запрещено, так же как, например, вы не можете переопределить `int operator+(int, int)`