# Создание и использование int_128

Tags: c++

Всем день добрый. Достаточно давно задавался вопросом, как сделать 128 битный int на c++.  Пробовал создавать структуру на 2 64 битных инта, но не понимаю, как сделать так, чтобы они считались единым числом, кто может дать подсказку и направление, буду очень благодарен. (Мне это нужно лишь для практики и более широкого понимания как работают структуры)

Comment: Вы и создали его как целочисленное комплексное число. Всё работает. Чтобы было одно число и один знак, нужно одно число сделать со знаком, второе - нет.

Comment: @AlexGlebe Спасибо, а если например мне нужно сразу при присваивании или в конструкторе задать большое число, как избежать переполнения?

Comment: Чтобы ваш тип был похож на встроенные целочисленные типы, [перегружайте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/31511) необходимые операторы. Если вас интересует как реализовать арифметические операции с вашим типом на уровне алгоритмов, то почитайте что-нибудь про [длинную арифметику](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0). Если нужно задать большое число как литерал, то его можно, например, задать как строковый литерал: `my_int128 x = "123...."` (это сработает при наличии соответствующего конструктора)...